# Motorola HandHeld Terminal MC75A does not Respond

Tags: windows-mobile, barcode, barcode-scanner, windows-mobile-6, motorola-emdk

I'm developing some project with Motorola MC75A. But I have some problem. I added barcode control to page and EnableScanner properties=false.

When I change barcode's properties EnableScanner=True and run the project, app doesn't respond.

Therefore I change EnableScanner=True to False.

I decide change this properties on codebehind. In Page_Activated Event EnableScanner=True, in Page_Deactivate EnableScanner=False.

Still my app doesn't respond on this page. What is the problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can take a while for these little devices to activate the Scanners. We leave ours on all the time.

How long are you giving the device to turn the scanner on?

Comment: I wait about ten minutes. It doesn't respond.

Comment: Does `EnableScanner=True` ever turn the scanner ON? It could be that the Symbol does not respond to that message.

Comment: I did some changes and problem was solved, thanks for attention.